# Selenium Webdriver - Cannot open and selct value from DropDown

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to open and select a value from `Passengers Dropdown`, without success.

Code snippet:

```java
public class SpiceJetTest {
    public static void main(String[] arge) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Liel PC\\Desktop\\TEST\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");

        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult")));    // id for Adult
        s.deselectByValue("2");
    }
}
```

***Could you suggest how to do it right?***

Answer (score 0):

Its hidden until you clicked onto the PASSENGERS drop down. please refer below codeto solve your issue.

**There are multiple ways to select option with drop down :**

```
 1. selectByVisibleText() 
 2. selectByValue()  
 3. selectByIndex()
```

**Solution to select value using `selectByVisibleText`**

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Liel PC\\Desktop\\TEST\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseURL = "https://www.spicejet.com/";

        driver.get(baseURL);

        driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).click();

        Select drpAdult = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult")));
        drpAdult.selectByVisibleText("1");
```

Comment: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Liel PC\\Desktop\\TEST\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).click();
        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("2");`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which version you are using:

Here my Code that work (For Chrome 80)

edit:
after working on it
there problem on the wait time (the page not load yet)

try that:

```
public static void main(String[] arge) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait ww= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20 ,2000);
    driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");

    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> conditionToCheck = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            //return (input.findElements(By.id("divpaxinfo")).size() > 0);
             return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("loaded")
                     || ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }

    };
    ww.until(conditionToCheck);
    driver.findElement(By.id("divpaxinfo")).click();
     Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult")));
    s.selectByValue("2");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector found for me 2 elements. This css selector: *#adultDropdown #ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult* found one, which you need. This kind of method can be used for waiting for element, before interact with it:

```
public static void waitForElementPresent(this IWebElement element)
        {
            try
            {
                wait.Until(driver => element.Displayed);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Assert.Fail("The element not found. The exception: \n" + e.GetType());
            }
        }
```

After element is found, then you can create a Select, and use this: *selectByValue("2");* method for selecting required value.
This is method mostly for working with IWebElements. If you are not using them, then this can be used for you:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Liel PC\\Desktop\\TEST\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");
        By elem = By.CssSelector("#adultDropdown #ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult");
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
        try
            {
                wait.Until(dr => ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException wte)
            {
                Logger.Info($"Timeout during wait. Exception: {wte.Message}");
            }
        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(elem));    // id for Adult
        s.deselectByValue("2");
```

Comment: Updated my post